# Python Data Structure Efficiency: Pandas vs Something Else

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures

I have a pandas dataframe that captures transactions within a for loop:

```
import pandas as pd
transaction_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['time', 'type', 'value'])
```

Through each iteration of the loop, I need to perform a sum on the transaction_df:

```
txn_sum = transaction_df[['type', 'value']].groupby('type').sum(numeric_only=True)
```

Given I need to run through a for loop 10,000+ iterations and the transaction table grows by 1,000 rows each iteration this structure is slowing linearly with the length of the transaction table. I cannot get rid of the for loop since each step is dependent on the prior step.

What would be a more efficient way to structure something like this? Is Pandas the right tool for the job? Is there anything that can better take advantage of multiple cores?

I've tried storing the txn_sum table at each step and then only summing the additions to the transaction_df. This gets in the right direction but still slow.

Comment: it isn't clear to me exactly what you are doing, but you should build up the whole dataframe *first*

Comment: it would be really helpful if you provided a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Don't grow the table, just add the new aggregate to the existing sum:

```
# initial total
total = (transaction_df[['type', 'value']]
         .groupby('type').sum(numeric_only=True)
        )

# then every time you have new data
for new_rows_df in data_generation_logic:
    new_subtotal = (new_rows_df[['type', 'value']]
                    .groupby('type').sum(numeric_only=True)
                   )
    total = total.add(new_subtotal, fill_value=0)
```